# Maven Surefire Appropriate use of Exclude

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, maven-surefire-plugin

I have found it impossible to make the Surefire `<exclude>` tag to work. I've tried on multiple occasions, and looked over numerous questions on stackoverflow and other sites, as well as the documentation for Surefire, so I'm resorting to asking it here. My situation is that I want to be able to control which tests are run through the mvn package command. I have a large number of tests, and I am often in a situation where I need to run all of them, and then progressively remove some from the list that needs running (because they are verified to be correct).

For example, let's say I have unit tests 1 through 20. The first time I execute mvn package, I want to run all 20 of them. I will then take the test logs, see if any of the tests executed without any issues, and then I would like to remove those tests from the next execution. The second time I execute, I will then want to run, say, tests 1 through 12, 13 through 15, and 17 through 20. It's unwieldy to run these tests individually, or to exclude them on every mvn CLI command.

My preferred solution would be to keep a list of excluded tests on the pom.xml, at least temporarily while I am going through this testing phase. Right now, my pom.xml looks as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>...</groupId>
  <artifactId>...</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>...</version>
  <name>...</name>
  <url>...</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      ...
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    ...
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
        <configuration>
          <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/CleanUpCodeMaatWrapperTest.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/AcdcWrapperTest.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/CSourceToDepsBuilderWrapperTest.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/JavaSourceToDepsBuilderWrapperTest.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/PipeExtractorWrapperTest.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/BatchCloneFinderWrapperTest.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/InferencerTest.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/TopicModelGeneratorTest.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
  </build>
</project>
```

I've left it as complete as possible so that no important information is left out. If more information from the pom.xml is needed to figure this out, I will be happy to provide it. Currently, this pom.xml, with the command `mvn package`, results in the execution of all tests in my `src/test` directory, including the ones listed above. Specifying the complete path, for example `src/test/AcdcWrapperTest.java`, gives me the same result. Executing all tests every time can currently take upwards of an hour, and by excluding maybe 3 or 4 of these tests which I know to be correct at this time (from executing them dozens of times) I would be able to bring it down by half of that. I don't want to permanently remove these tests, or have to rename them in order for Surefire to skip them, as that too is unwieldy. Any help would be enormously appreciated, as I've genuinely been trying to solve this for months at this point.

Comment: Really you test is in this directory `src/test/AcdcWrapperTest.java` ?

Comment: No, sorry, I thought that'd be sufficient information. The tests are in their own package directories inside ```src/test/java/...```. The directory structure here follows the maven convention and mirrors the structure in ```src/main/java/...```. Also to clarify, what I meant is that by giving their complete path, it also still executes the excluded tests.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such `groupId` as **org.apache.maven.plugin** but there is org.apache.maven.plugin**s**, see the official [docs](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html).

Change to this config and it will work:

```
...
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
...
```